# Tricky Differential Equation Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am unsure of how to tackle the following differential equation:

$$ dx+ x\,dy = e^{-y}\sec^2y\,dy$$

I have done the following so far:

$$dx + x\,dy = e^{-y} \sec^2y \, dy$$

$$=>dx = e^{-y} \sec^2y \, dy - x \, dy$$

$$=>dx = (e^{-y} \sec^2y - x) \, dy$$

$$=>dx/dy = (e^{-y}) \sec^2y - x $$

Is this the correct approach? How can the problem be solved after this?

(Not homework: preparing for a test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as:
$$\frac{dx}{dy} + x = e^{-y} \sec^2y$$

This can now be tackled with an 'Integrating Factor' which in this case is $e^y$.

So, multiply both sides by $e^y$:
$$e^y\frac{dx}{dy} + xe^y = \sec^2y$$

The LHS is nothing but the derivative of $xe^y$ with respect to $y.$

We have
$$\frac{d(xe^y)}{dy}= \sec^2y$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $y$:
$$xe^y=\tan(y)+c$$

Thus,
$$x=e^{-y}\tan(y)+ce^{-y}$$

where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Note: Any equation of the form 
$$\frac{dx}{dy} + xP(y) = Q(y)$$
can be tackled using an Integrating Factor.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Rewrite/Simplify it as:

$$e^y~dx + (x e^y - \sec^2 y)~ dy = 0$$

Now, check this as being an Exact Equation to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah! But if you just want to, you can also use the other method which is Linear Differential equation, where in the standard solution goes like this: dx/dy+xP(y)=Q(y)--> if eq. is linear in x; dy/dx+yP(x)=Q(x)--> if eq. is linear in y.

since the given problem is linear in x, use dx/dy+xP(y)=Q(y)
where P(y)=1 and Q(y)=e^(−y)sec^(2)y
and IF (Integrating factor): e^(integral of P(y) or e [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wV7n.png)

then use the formula:
x*IF=[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqsN9.png)(IF * Q(y))dy + C
thus,
x*e^(y)=tan^(2)y+C [this is the final answer in general form ]